# How can I store and subscribe component state to redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a container "HomeIndexView" and component "Table"
And I have both global and local component state of table.

Global table states are like below,

```
const initialState = {
   allTables: [],
   showForm: false,
   fetching: true,
   formErrors: null,
 };
```

and local component state of table is like below,

```
 componentWillMount() {
   this.setInitialState();
  }

 setInitialState() {
  this.setState({ tableBusy: false });
 }
```

When a user logs in, in HomeIndexView, it shows all tables from data base through fetching. 
So what I want to do is that  connecting local component state to redux store so that when it changes state false to true, it changes background color of table. How should I connect local state to redux store? and should I create separate reducer and action for the local component's state?

Thanks in advance

--EDIT 1

```
import Table                from '../../components/tables/table';
```

I am importing LocalComponent (Table) to HomeIndexView to show. 
In my HomeIndexView, it renders all tables from database,

```
_renderAllTables() {
 const { fetching } = this.props;

let content = false;


if(!fetching) {
  content = (
    <div className="tables-wrapper">
      {::this._renderTables(this.props.tables.allTables)}
    </div>
    );
 }


return (
  <section>
    <header className="view-header">
      <h3>All Tables</h3>
    </header>
    {content}
  </section>
);
}


 _renderTables(tables) {


    return tables.map((table) => {
        return <Table
            key={table.id}
            dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
            {...table} />;               
    });

   }

  render() {
   return (
   <div className="view-container tables index">
    {::this._renderAllTables()}
   </div>
   );
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'global' state?  Do you mean you have created a Redux store or is it just the `initialState` object you defined?  If so, where.  Can you elaborate on the component hierarchy where the above states reside?

Comment: Yes I have created a Redux store and `const initialState ={` is global state of Table component. The component hierarchy is Authenticated container >HomeIndexView > Table Component

Comment: For the local component, I created because I want each table from database to have a state of tableBusy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'react-redux'` library contains binding methods between React and Redux.  If you haven't done so already, I really recommend checking out 
[Dan Abramov's: **'Getting into Redux'**](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) series of videos.

He goes into a good amount of detail about ***how*** to build a working Redux application from scratch and then how to do the same in conjunction with React (again from scratch).

He finalises on the use of the `'react-redux'` helper library to make wiring up React with Redux easier.

The resulting solution for you would be to:

- Use the `connect` method in Redux to create a Redux container component (just a term for a React component with Redux bindings)

  - `mapStateToProps` receives updates on the current state of the store which you can map to the target components `props`.  Yo'd use this to get the current state of the store for use in your component
  - `mapDispatchToProps` which gets the store's dispatch action which you can use to bind action creators to (to update the store).  You'd use this to connect the action creators that update the state of your store.

Comment: It's very messy though and hooks your component into Redux. Also you lose function signatures in TS because of mapDispatchToProps instead of calling store functions directly.

Comment: @OliverDixon: Do you have a solution to the OP’s question that doesn’t “hook into” Redux? For posterity (and in case the original question changes) the OP’s question was is: “How can  I store and subscribe Component state to **redux** store?”

Comment: Yes, use connect to match the components to props only. Do not use dispatch. (It's even more testable this way). Do direct calls to the store (abstracted behind functions of course). This way your component will act/look like regular React component without all the Redux mess, but still using Redux with all the same possibilities of middleware.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've already setup your reducers and actions. Now the only thing you need to do is dispatch an action from your `LocalComponent`.

Lets say you've a method called `toggleTableState` for updating the state `tableBusy` of your `LocalComponent`.

**LocalComponent.js**

---

```
import React, { PureComponent, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions`;

@connect(
  (state, props) => ({
    isTableBusy: state.isTableBusy,
  }),
  {
    toggleTableGlobalState: actions.toggleTableGlobalState,
  })
export default class LocalComponent extends PureComponent {

    static propTypes = {
        toggleTableGlobalState: PropTypes.func,
        isTableBusy: PropTypes.bool,
    }

    ...

    toggleTableState() {
        this.setState({ tableBusy: !this.state.tableBusy });   
        this.props.toggleTableGlobalState(!this.state.tableBusy);
    }

    ...

}
```

**actions.js**

---

```
export const TOGGLE_TABLE_STATE = 'TOGGLE_TABLE_STATE';

export function toggleTableGlobalState(tableState) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_TABLE_STATE, tableState };
}
```

**reducer.js**

---

```
import { TOGGLE_TABLE_STATE } from './actions';

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {

        ...

        case TOGGLE_TABLE_STATE:
            return { ...state, isTableBusy: action.tableState };
            break;
        ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for comment, I tried to implement this solution,  but when I define the component as `PureComponent` , it triggers Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined at _inherts... So i tried to define super expression, by adding `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }` but it still triggers same error... Do you have any idea with this??

Comment: can you show me how you're importing `LocalComponent` and where it is being used? Also what version of React are you using?

Comment: I think 3.8.6 is your npm version. Try `npm list --depth=0 | grep react`

Comment: Oops sorry, `├── babel-preset-react@6.16.0
├── react@0.14.8
├── react-addons-css-transition-group@0.14.8
├── react-dom@0.14.8
├── react-redux@4.4.5
├── react-router@2.8.1
├── react-router-redux@4.0.6
`

Comment: `React.PureComponent` is exactly like `React.Component` but implements `shouldComponentUpdate()` with a shallow prop and state comparison. `PureComponent` is essentially a base class to extend with `PureRenderMixin` built in. It was shipped with React v15.3.0, so if you're using any previous version of React, use `Component` instead of `PureComponent`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128559/discussion-between-free-soul-and-d-r).